# Word that means to speak about nothing important

Tags: word-usage

What word means to speak about nothing important? Basically, I want something the opposite of ranting. 
I know the word bable, but it does not fit into the context I want.

### Babble:

> talk rapidly and continuously in a foolish, excited, or incomprehensible way.

I want a word with a more positive and less rude connotation.

Chatter also won't work for me because it is too informal.

### Chatter

> talk rapidly or incessantly about trivial matters.

Definitions taken from the google dictionary extension.

Comment: **Babble**, probably related to a tower of a similar name.

Comment: Babble is of a tower of similar nature, I agree. However, it also means to talk quickly, which is not exactly what I am looking for. Something more generic?

Comment: There's 'natter' (infamously part of 'nattering nabobs of negativism').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some synonyms with the similar meaning of 'chatting'.

I would recommend 
'***To prate***'.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prate#other-words):

***prate***

verb

intransitive verb

: to talk long and idly

: CHATTER